# where is tradingview pine js document?

Tags: tradingview-api

I developing indicator to use pine.js
and i tried find document but there is no document about pine.js

do you know where is the document

in the chat library github there is no pine.js

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? Im also stuck since the charting lib documentation isnt really explaining things about this.